# Existence of intermediate field extensions for tamely ramified p-adic extensions

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, galois-theory, p-adic-numbers, field-extensions

Let $p$ be a prime, and let $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ be a tamely ramified finite extension of degree $n$.  Let $q$ be a prime factor of $n$ with $q\neq p$.  Must there exist an intermediate extension $L$ (with $\mathbb{Q}_p\subset L\subset K$) of degree $q$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

---

Some partial progress, following Hasse's "Number Theory", Chapter 16:

We can decompose our field extension as $\mathbb{Q}_p\subset K^{ur}\subset K$, where $K^{ur}$ is the maximal unramified subextension. Let $e=[K:K^{ur}]$ and $f=[K^{ur}:\mathbb{Q}_p]$. If $q$ divides $f$, we are done, since $K^{ur}/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is Galois with cyclic Galois group.

Otherwise, write $K^{ur}=\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta,(up\zeta^r)^{1/e})$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $(p^f-1)st$ root of unity, $u$ is a unit in the $p$-adic integers, and $0\leq r<\gcd(p^f-1,e)$.  If $\gcd(p^f-1,e)=1$, then $K$ contains $\mathbb{Q}_p((up)^{1/e})$, and thus the intermediate field $\mathbb{Q}_p((up)^{1/q})$, which has degree $q$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

We can also reduce to the case of $e=q$, by considering the subfield $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta,(up\zeta^r)^{1/q})$.  Since $q$ is prime and we dealt with the relatively prime case, we need only consider the case of $q$ dividing $p^f-1$.  Note that if $q$ divides $p-1$, we have that $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta,(up\zeta^r)^{1/q})$ is an abelian Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, also leading to the desired extension of degree $q$.  That leaves the case of $q$ not dividing $p-1$ but still dividing $p^f-1$; in these cases, the extension is not Galois.  Can we say anything about intermediate extensions of degree $q$ in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. For example the group $S_3\times C_3$ occurs (as TransitiveGroup(6,5)) as the Galois group of an (automatically tame) extension of $\mathbb{Q}_5$ (and more generally over $\mathbb{Q} _p$ for all odd primes $p\equiv 2$ mod $3$, by taking the compositum of the unramified degree-$3$ extension with the splitting field of $x^3-p$), see https://www.lmfdb.org/padicField/5.6.4.2 . The point stabilizer (namely, the diagonal subgroup $C_3$) is contained in a maximal subgroup of index 2, but not one of index 3, meaning that there is a tame degree 6 extension not containing a degree 3 subextension.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample! A follow-up question:  what if we ask that q is the smallest prime factor of n (and we still assume  q≠p)?  Can we still find counterexamples?

Comment: @RalphMorrison For this, there should be no counterexamples. Your considerations already show that there is always a subfield $F$ of *some* prime degree $\ell$, and inductively, between $K$ and $F$ is some intermediate field of degree $q$ (the smallest prime dividing $n/\ell$). It then suffices to solve the case $[K:\mathbb{Q}_p] = q\ell$, with $q<\ell$ both prime. As you deduce, one can reduce to the case $p^\ell \equiv 1$ mod $q$ and $p\ne 1$ mod $q$. But this means $ord_q(p) = \ell > q$, a contradiction.